# What are ai_user and ai_session cookies in ASP NET Core Identity and how to configure it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am new to ASP net core and learning how identity works. I am wondering what are ai_user and ai_session cookies added to the requests when using identity.
[Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKcOB.png)

I guess cookies are session management related. I tried to figure out how to disable /configure it, but didn't find anything.

Is there a way to disable or configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ai_user` and `ai_session` is about `Application Insights`. Here's an introduction to those:

> `SessionTelemetryInitializer` updates the `Id` property of the `Session` context for all telemetry items with value extracted from the `ai_session` cookie generated by the ApplicationInsights JavaScript instrumentation code running in the user's browser.
>
> `UserTelemetryInitializer` updates the `Id` and `AcquisitionDate` properties of User context for all telemetry items with values extracted from the `ai_user` cookie generated by the Application Insights JavaScript instrumentation code running in the user's browser.
> [image]

You can read this document to learn more about [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config).